# LINQ to SQL Server 2000: "Must declare variable '@p0'"

Tags: linq, sql-server-2000

I've created this simple LINQ query:

```
var result = from invoice in invoiceTable
             where invoice.Id == 1
             select invoice.Document;
```

It generates this SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[Document]
FROM [Invoice] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0
```

Whenever I run it though I get this error:

(ODBC)

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the variable '@p0'.

(OleDb)

> Must declare the variable '@p0'.

I remember reading that OleDb and ADO.NET does not support named parameters on SQL Server 2000. Is this problem related to that issue, or am I doing something else wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**

This does seem to be a provider issue.  I tried the same query against SQL Server 2008 using the SQL Client data provider and it worked fine.  Unfortunately, this provider does not work with SQL Server 2000.

When I tried using the ODBC and OLEDB providers with SQL Server 2008 I got the same errors.

Does anyone know of a suitable workaround?

**UPDATE 2:**

It turns out the SQL Client provider **does** work with SQL Server 2000.  Just not from within Visual Studio 2010.  I changed the provider and the query works now.

Comment: When you say "run it through" - you mean executing the actual query, or trying the generated SQL through a profiler?

Comment: Are you using Linq to Sql or Entity Framework?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm executing the actual query ("though" not "through").  The SQL I pasted is what shows up in the profiler, and the debugger when I try to evaluate the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the SQL Client provider does work with SQL Server 2000. Just not from within Visual Studio 2010. I changed the provider and the query works now.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using an ODBC provider, it will not work. Change to SqlClient.