# Linq to SQL not filling in integer parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm using Linq to SQL to query a table, code is below:

```
else if (int.TryParse(searchstring, out isID))
{
    var events = from e in db.ov_Events
                 where e.Event_Id == isID
                 select e;

    success = true;
    error = "";
    return events.ToList();
}
```

This section of code performs the following query:

```
SELECT [t0].[Event_Id], [t0].[Event_Name]...
FROM [dbo].[ov_Events] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Event_Id] = @p0
```

This then returns an error from the database "Must declare scalar variable @p0".

I don't understand why linq isn't supplying the variable to the server (SQL Server Express 2014).

I've even tried the following:

```
    var events = from e in db.ov_Events
                 where e.Event_Id == 1
                 select e;
```

This still runs the same exact query, not sure where I've gone wrong?

Full code below:

```
using (DB_v1DataContext db = new DB_v1DataContext(Con)) {
    int isID;
    try {
        if (searchstring == "") {
            var events = from e in db.ov_Events
                         select e;
            success = true;
            error = "";
            return events.ToList();
        } else if (int.TryParse(searchstring, out isID)) {
            var events = from e in db.ov_Events
                         where e.Event_Id == isID
                         select e;
            success = true;
            error = "";
            return events.ToList();
        } else {
            var events = from e in db.ov_Events
                         where e.Event_Name.Contains(searchstring) 
                         || e.Event_Notes.Contains(searchstring)
                         select e;

            success = true;
            error = "";
            return events.ToList();

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        success = false;
        error = "Error Getting Events:" + ex.Message;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in linq2sql. See if you can get it to break in an isolated scenario without any conditionals, and file a bug report.

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016456/linq-to-sql-server-2000-must-declare-variable-p0